# MySQL LEFT JOIN multiple tables not joining correctly

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to use multiple linked LEFT JOINs in order to populate fields in a SELECT query, however I can't get the logic quite right. I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `due_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

CREATE TABLE `role_group` (
  `role_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

I want to return the role name for all records that have a group ID that matches a record in `role_group` but `NULL` otherwise.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  t.group_id,
  t.title,
  t.due_date,
  r.name
FROM 
  tasks t
LEFT JOIN 
  role_group rg ON t.group_id = rg.group_id
LEFT JOIN 
  role r ON r.id = rg.role_id;
```

At the moment the query just returns `NULL` in `role.name` regardless of whether there are matching records.

EDIT: This was a schoolboy error - there were not matching records in `role_group` for the records in `tasks`. Sorry for wasting contributors' time on this one. Not sure whether I should delete, or?

Comment: Post sample data and expected result. I'm pretty sure you will find the problem while doing that. Read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Note that if you have a match in `role_group` that doesn't mean that you also have a match in `role`.